# How can I delete all this in my nginx.d/default.conf file;

Tags: bash, ubuntu, nginx

```
server {
  server_name xxx.com;
  location / {
    client_max_body_size 200M;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
  listen 80;
}
```

I used `sed -i "/server_name $server/,+9d" $FILE`

```
server {
}
```

still appear.

thank you all

Comment: Using your command I  get: `server {` not `server { }`. Do you want to remove absolutely all lines?

Comment: yes , I get a host name from the user and I want to delete all the server object in the nginx file that matches this name.

Comment: Thank you. I understand better.

Comment: About `server_name xxx.com` is that line just one time in all your file? or you can have several lines like `server_name example.com`?

Comment: no I just want to delete all this object `server {
  server_name xxx.com;
  location / {
    client_max_body_size 200M;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
  listen 80;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a possible solution but I think there are better ways to solve it

What you need is to get the number of the matched line and subtract it 1:

```bash
number=$(($(sed -n "/server_name $server/{=}" $FILE) - 1))
```

Finally you will have to remove the line that `$number` contains and remove the following 9 lines of the matched line (`"/server_name $server/,+9d"`):

```bash
#You should check if the line returned is >= 0
[ $number -ge 0 ] && {
  sed -i -e "${number}d" -e "/server_name xxx.com/,+9d" $FILE
}
```

**Important:** This code only works when there is just one line (e.g. `server_name xxx.com;`) in other words the value returned by `$(sed -n "/server_name $server/{=}" $FILE)` must be just one number.